# Cosmos Db - insert if not exists

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, bulkinsert, conflict

Dear Cosmos fellow members,

I am creating Azure Function (Python) with CosmosTrigger that:

- reads data from source_collection
- writes data to target_collection (only if document does not exist)

To achieve "insert if not exists" functionality I configured target_collection with unique key "name".

Example:

1. write to target_collection `{"name": "John", "id": "1"}` => OK
2. write to target_collection `[{"name": "John", "id": "2"}, {"name": "Mary", "id": "3"}]` => System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.CosmosTrigger. Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Entity with the specified id already exists in the system.

Unique key "name": "John" already exists in target_collection. So outdocs: func.Out[func.Document], outdocs.set() returns conflict 409 and "Mary" never gets written to target_collection.

Important: when I upload json with array of items from Data Explorer to target_collection, all conflicts return an error, but all items get processed.
When I try to write it from Azure function, first conflict raises an error and remaining items never make it to target_collection.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to ignore raised errors and process whole array of items with func.Out[func.Document].set() ?
2. Alternatively could you please advise me what would be the best way to implement bulk "insert if not exist" behaviour in Cosmos?

```
def main(docs: func.DocumentList, outdocs: func.Out[func.Document]) -> str:
  compl_docs = func.DocumentList()

    compl_docs_dict = {
      "name": "John",
      "id": "2"
    }

    compl_docs.append(func.Document.from_dict(compl_docs_dict))

    compl_docs_dict = {
      "name": "Mary",
      "id": "3"
    }

    compl_docs.append(func.Document.from_dict(compl_docs_dict))

  outdocs.set(compl_docs)
```

Comment: Can you share the code of how you are doing the write? "insert if not exists" in Cosmos DB is Upsert. The problem is this won't solve your issue. Your issue is not that a Create fails because the document already exists, it fails because of a violation of a Unique Key constraint (because of `name`). In your case, the document with `id` 2 is a different document than the one with `id` 1, but they are having the same `name` which violates the Unique Key policy.

Comment: Maybe I will rephrase - I want to achieve "don't insert if document exists". I planned to use Unique Key constraint to handle duplicates automatically but it is throwing errors on top. I want to send ["John", "Mary"] in one function run. And if there is already "John" in collection, only "Mary" gets written. Currently I get error after "John" unique key violation and "Mary" never gets processed.

Comment: The Cosmos DB output binding uses Upsert, sadly there is no option to change that behavior. Your only option seems to be maintaining the SDK client independently (not use the Output Binding). That way you can issue a Create (instead of Upsert) and handle the Conflict (item already exists).

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION
this is how insert-if-not-exist can be done in cosmos:

1. create cosmos client in your code and use ExecuteProcedure to send docs from azure function to cosmos procedure
2. add stored procedure to your cosmos collection that handles conflicts. You can find bulkUpsert_v_2 from Microsoft and modify it so when conflict 409 occurs, nothing will be written to cosmos.